# Problems in dependencies using maven with ecplise

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, m2eclipse

I do not know a lot about Maven, only the basics and that this causing me some problems.

I'm using Ecplise Luna with maven (the EMBEDDED version 3.2.1 / 1.5.1.50109-1819) to manage my project. also installed JBoss Tools plugin to send my project to OpenShift. So far so good.

However, I'm facing some errors in OpenShift and researching in forums discovered that the problem is related to the 5.0.8 version of mysql-connector-java. So I went in pom.xml file from my maven project and changed the version of mysql-connector-java 5.0.8 to 5.1.38, saved the pom and theoretically my maven should download the version the new version (5.1.38) mysql-connector-java and delete the old (5.0.8), right?
Well, if that's what should happen, it is not what is happening. I could not find any errors, but in my lib folder there is only the 5.0.8 version of mysql-connector-java.

Strange that when I give clean install to build is successfully generated, and MyApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT / WEB-INF / lib is generated mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar file and mysql-connector -java-5.1.38.jar.

Why this is happening? the little I understand, the maven should not replace the 5.0.8 version for 5.1.38, since I changed the version in pom.xml?

Any idea what's going on?

My pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Picos</groupId>
  <artifactId>Picos</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <version>5.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
      <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.10</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.38</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.10</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.21</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>2.21</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
      <version>2.21</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.jvnet.mimepull</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jvnet.mimepull</groupId>
      <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.21</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ganyo</groupId>
      <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>prime-repo</id>
      <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
      <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>D:\Meus documentos\Projetos\Thiago\app Picos\Workspace\Picos\src</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>D:\Meus documentos\Projetos\Thiago\app Picos\Workspace\Picos\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>D:\Meus documentos\Projetos\Thiago\app Picos\Workspace\Picos\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>D:\Meus documentos\Projetos\Thiago\app Picos\Workspace\Picos\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>D:\Meus documentos\Projetos\Thiago\app Picos\Workspace\Picos\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>D:\Meus documentos\Projetos\Thiago\app Picos\Workspace\Picos\src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>D:\Meus documentos\Projetos\Thiago\app Picos\Workspace\Picos\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>D:\Meus documentos\Projetos\Thiago\app Picos\Workspace\Picos\target</directory>
    <finalName>Picos-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
              <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>D:\Meus documentos\Projetos\Thiago\app Picos\Workspace\Picos\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>D:\Meus documentos\Projetos\Thiago\app Picos\Workspace\Picos\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>D:\Meus documentos\Projetos\Thiago\app Picos\Workspace\Picos\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>D:\Meus documentos\Projetos\Thiago\app Picos\Workspace\Picos\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>openshift</id>
      <build>
        <finalName>Picos</finalName>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
              <warName>ROOT</warName>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Could you post your POM?

Comment: is there. look my edit

Comment: Don't use embedded maven. Install it on your machine and configure it on eclipse. Also changing a dependency will not delete the old one. Maven will only update the references to your project. There are lots of problems with embedded version. I'm saying that out of experience not based in any post or bug released by the community, since it was bugged I always use an external version and it always work fine.

Comment: I tried to install the external Maven from a tutorial, but when I go to build get this error
Errors occurred During the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'peaks'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins: maven-resources-plugin: 2.6 or one of its dependencies Could Not Be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor is org.apache.maven.plugins: maven-Resources- plugin: jar: 2.6

Comment: This may not be your problem botu your `D:\Meus documentos\Projetos\Thiago\app Picos\Workspace\Picos\` are good pratice. Remember that everything in Maven is relative to the basedir, i.e. the location of the POM. So you can actually drop that completely.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand exactly what you mean

Comment: @sThiago Is the problem fixed?

Comment: Yes I fixed the problem.It was a problem in proxy my settings.xml file

Comment: Of course, I had to use the external version of maven, as said Jorge Campos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven does not import the dependencies into the 'lib'-folder of the eclipse project. Instead it will be downloaded to the local maven repository (at USER_HOME/.m2/repository). When the project is built, maven will copy all contents of your projects 'lib' folder and additionally include the referenced jars from your local repository.

I suspect that you saved the old version inside the 'lib' folder, which is why you end up with both versions.